# add quantity on product add-on in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Spectralock Pro Premium -- client is editing and needs a solution -- can only set quantity for whole order --- is it possible to make this so users can set quantity for attributes / add-ons? --- example: Spectralock Pro Premium, option 1 (x4) and option 2 (x1) ?

Comment: please try to provide some code and what you achieved so far ?

Comment: which product addon are you using

Comment: Woocommerce product add-on